# Passing the mysql connection between modules in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, discord.js, node-mysql

There were several similar questions, but I still can't find the answer.
I'm creating a discord bot in discord.js where each command is a separate module and I don't know how to solve transfer a connection to each file.

This is my file tree:

```
bot
├─index.js
├─my_modules/
│ └─db.js
└─commands/
  ├─exampleCommand.js
  ├─...
  └─subCommandsForExampleCommand/
    ├─subCommand1.js
    └─...
```

db.js:

```
const mysql = require(`mysql`);

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    //user, pass, etc..
});

//some db functions

module.exports = conn;
```

From the node.js documentation:

> Modules are cached based on their resolved filename. Since modules may
>   resolve to a different filename based on the location of the calling
>   module (loading from node_modules folders), it is not a guarantee that
>   require('foo') will always return the exact same object, if it would
>   resolve to different files.

Using `` require(`./my_modules/database.js`) `` in `index.js` and `` require(`../../my_modules/database.js`) `` in `subCommand1.js` may return different instances. So how best to transfer the connection between files?

Pass the connection as an argument from the `index` to `exampleCommand` and from here to `subCommand1`, or set a global variable in the index and using it in other files?

Comment: Most of the time a global shared DB connection is a bad idea, especially if you have a long running application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine the way you did it. 
And the docs mean that if you have multiple files named `db.js` in different places, you may happen to load different files depending on where you're loading from. I.e. if you just `require('moduleName')` there's a resolving mechanism which starts with the current directory and then moves on to other places like node modules etc. As long as you have one `db.js` and also no node modules named similarly, you should be ok.